# Multiple Database Connections slow down my website PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection

I am new and I tried to find my answer in the questions but I did not find something even close.

I have a website that is displaying data from 6 different databases. This is the code i use to connect the databases:

```
<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect("server","user","password","database");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT count(*) as new_orders FROM orders where print=0");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['new_orders'];
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I used this code and only change the connection credentials for all the 6 databases since they have the same table. The problem is that I have to used the 6 connections in the same php page but every time I open my file dashboard.php, it shows all the information I need from the 6 databases but it takes around 30 seconds to load the page.

As you can see my query is very simple, just count the orders and that's it ! ... I was researching and I found that I probably need indexes, well I create the indexes for the tables in the databases but nothing changed.

Could you please help me with this? Any ideas of what the problem may be. This page is like the first page of my website so it is always visit and people have to wait like 30 seconds to see the page.

Thank you for the help you can provide me

Regards,

Oscar Rabines

Comment: Are your sure that database connection is that point that slow down script execution? I'd recommend you to make profiling on your php script execution. When you get such information you can determine which part of your php is slowing script.

Answer (score 0):

Did you know you can improve your website performance by using gzip or something similar?
Also I recommend using a single class for the MySQL server connection. It makes your code much better readable.
Which indexes do you used?
Also try to use just one or two databases on one server with tables instead of databases.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to multiple databases will always be slow. Is there any reason why you need them in separate databases.

It would probably be easier, especially if there is not a massive amount of data to simply add an extra table for identifying with the fields id and name

e.g

1 = database 1 ect

then on the tables your checking for information to add another field such as database. then for each

SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE database = '1';

Answer (score 0):

"This page is like the first page of my website so it is always visit and people have to wait like 30 seconds to see the page."

You could use AJAX to load the data asynchronously.That would at least prevent people closing your page before its loaded.